# Basic emberjs app not working

Tags: ember.js

I'm newbie in emberjs app development. And I want to use emberjs for prototype "transaction page" for my project.

The core idea is simple. I have a list of transactions, which i want to show for user.

I done simple skeleton of my page on emberjs, but it's not working correctly.
It's here - http://jsbin.com/udinar/1/edit

TransitionTo in router i used specially, because i want to add some functional section on page in future.

And I will be grateful for comments on the improvement of my code, because maybe I do not fully understand all the concepts emberjs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is you working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udinar/10/edit).

There where some naming conventions problems, the most problematic part was the `transactions_list` it was not interpreted correctly and thus not working. I've renamed everything to simple `transactions`. Also, you did try to call `create` on the controller that get's automatically instantiated, this is changed to `extend`, and therefore you did try to use the still not instantiated controller in the routes `setupController` hook, etc.
I've also added a button so you can test your controller's `addTransaction` function.

Here is the code that works:

```
/**************************
* Application
**************************/

App = Em.Application.create({
  ready: function () {
    alert("App was loaded successfully");
  },
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
  rootElement: '#center'
});

/**************************
* Routes
**************************/

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("index", {path : "/"});
  this.route("transactions", {path : "/transactions"});
});

App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo("transactions");
  }
});

App.TransactionsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return [App.Transaction.create({id : 1,
         general_status: 'Done',
         user1_status: 'Done',
         user2_status: 'Done'
      }),
      App.Transaction.create({id : 2,
         general_status: 'In progress',
         user1_status: 'Waiting confirm',
         user2_status: 'Done'
      })
    ];
   }
});

/**************************
* Models
**************************/

App.Transaction = Em.Object.extend({
  id: null,
  general_status: null,
  user1_status: null,
  user2_status: null,
  details: null
});

/**************************
* Views
**************************/

App.TransactionsView = Em.View.extend({
  templateName: 'transactions'
});

/**************************
* Controllers
**************************/

App.TransactionsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  addTransaction: function(transaction) {
    console.log(transaction);
    //this.pushObject(transaction);
  }
});
```

Edit: after your comment, to dynamically retrive your model via ajax you should do:

```
App.TransactionsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function () {
    return App.Transaction.find();
  }
});
```

And then in your controller implement your CRUD methods

```
App.TransactionsController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  add: function(transaction) {
    //your implementation
  },
  delete: function(transaction) {
    //your implementation
  },
  edit: function(transaction) {
    //your implementation
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

Here is your *new* working [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/udinar/20/edit). I've added ember-data and defined a store, the store only exists using ember-data. I've also defined the Fixtures for the transactions so you will have a place to retrieve from, if your data comes from an API you should switch to the RESTAdapter.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But after your change, model is statically defined in router. I want to dinamically generate list of transaction from server via ajax (and change it on user actions). I thought that in such a case, the list of transactions must be stored in the controller and provided methods for changing it (add, delete, etc.) Is this true? And if it so - how to properly implement it?

Comment: Ok. But I have a problem again :) You are using method "find" of model in TransactionRouter, but where's the store itself, and how to access it (where the "find" method will be search models?)? I think that store is in variable "content" of TransactionController. Is it so? And I want to initialize my transaction list on page load. I think that I can do this in setupController method of Router. Is it so? I try to realize/change this in http://jsbin.com/udinar/18/edit and it's not working... Excuse me for a stupid questions and thanks you again :)

Comment: Don't worry there are no stupid questions :) see the edit's to my answer, hope this will get you forward with your project.

Comment: Official ember.js documents states that Ember.Data are actively developing (and it's not recommended for use). And I want to fully control interaction with the server by myself (handle errors and etc). Can you give some tips how to do this without Ember.Data? Really thanks for your help - my understanding is growing day by day :)

Comment: yeah, ember-data is a WIP and is changing very rapidly. To learn how to go about using ember without ember-data you should definitely take a look at the discourse.org project, it's build without ember-data and open source (https://github.com/discourse/discourse), also have a look at this blog post (http://eviltrout.com/2013/03/23/ember-without-data.html) this should help growing your understanding even more :)

Comment: Great thanks for you help. This step is finished - moved on next :)